# Get form to submit on same page?

Tags: php, html, forms, xampp, submission

Okay so, I've posted this already but still haven't found a solution. I can't seem make my form stay on the same page and I've basically tried EVERYTHING I could possibly think of.

```
    <?php include("inc\incfiles\header.inc.php"); ?>
    <?php
      $reg = @$_POST['reg'];
       //declaring variables to prevent errors 
         $fn = $ln = $un = $em = $em2 = $pswd = $pswd2 = $d = $u_check = ""; 

       /*$fn = ""; //First Name
         $ln = ""; //Last Name
         $un = ""; //Username
         $em = ""; //Email
         $em2 = ""; //Email 2
         $pawd = ""; //:Password
         $pawd2 = ""; //Password 2
         $d = ""; //Sign up Date
         $u_check = ""; //Check if username exists*/
         //registration form
         $fn = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['fname']);
         $ln = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['lname']); 
         $un = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['username']); 
         $em = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['email']); 
         $em2 = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['email2']); 
         $pswd = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['password']); 
         $pswd2 = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['password2']); 
         $d = date("Y-m-d"); //Year - Month - Day 

       if ($reg) 
       { 
       //check all of the fields have been filled in
       if ($fn && $ln && $un && $em && $em2 && $pswd && $pswd2) {

       }
       else{
       echo "please fill in all fields...";
        }
        }
        ?>

       <table class="homepageTable">
        <tr>

    <td width="60%" valign="top">
    <center><h2>Join the community today!</h2></center>
<center><img src="images/photo.png" width="500"></center>
 <form>
</td>
<td width="40%" valign="top">
<h2>Get started below...</h2>  
<form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fn; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $ln; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $un; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $em; ?>">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Repeat Email" value="<?php echo $em2; ?>"/>
      <input type="password" size="32" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <input type="password" size="32" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password"/><br />
      <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!"/>

      </form>
      </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
```

My biggest problem is with the:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fn; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $ln; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $un; ?>"/>
      <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $em; ?>">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Repeat Email" value="<?php echo $em2; ?>"/>
      <input type="password" size="32" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <input type="password" size="32" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password"/><br />
      <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!"/>

      </form>
```

I want to be able to press the submit button and have it stay on the same page. 
I've tried leaving the  blank I've tried a few other suggestions but I keep coming up with nothing. I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days now and it just won't budge. When pressing the submit button on my site in xampp, it just takes me to another page that says OBJECT NOT FOUND...etc.

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated! I really don't want to have to start all over with my coding just because of one mistake.

Header.inc.php

```
<?php 
include("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php"); 
?> 
<html>
<head>
<link href="css\main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<title>website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerMenu">
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/Logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="search_box">
            <form method="GET" action="search.php" id="search">
            <input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search..."
            </form>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#">Log in</a>
     </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. If you feel your identical earlier version isn't getting attention, you can edit it which acts to dump it up to the top of the list.

Comment: @MarcB even I think the code and error are same on these 2 questions!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. I didn't think it would be a big deal to post a duplicate.

Comment: just edit your previous question and add the portion of code you've added here. That'll bring your problem on top of the queue. And delete this question :)

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet They are the same! I wasn't trying to not make them the same. As you can see in the first sentence I stated that I already posted this before.

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet Well it won't let me delete this one because it already has answers?

Comment: what is in `inc\incfiles\header.inc.php`? could it have some php or javascript code that redirects on post or changes the form action on form submit?

Comment: @Sean Well, I don't see anything off about it but I'll add it so you can get a look at it.

Comment: I don't see anything there. What is the the file names between this page and the page it is going to - ie. `home.php` -> `otherpage.php`?

Comment: @Sean I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I only have one page which is the index.php

Comment: So in you browser you have `http://website.com/index.php`, but when you submit the form, you said you get a white page that says `Object not found! The requested URL ... Error 404 ...`. What is the browser url at this time? is it still `http://website.com/index.php` or is it now something else, ie. `http://website.com/NewPageName.php`

Comment: @Sean Here is what I get: http:// localhost/sites/socialnetwork/search.php?firstname=&lastname=&username=&email=&email2=&password=&password2=&reg=Sign+Up%21

Comment: You said that your only page is `index.php`. So are you saying that on form submit your `index.php` is now becoming `http://localhost/sites/socialnetwork/search.php?firstname=&lastname=&username=&email=&email2=&password=&password2=&reg=Sign+Up%21`? That looks more like you have `<form action="search.php" method="get">` or `<form action="search.php">` (missing the method)

Comment: @Sean Yes! That's correct. I've only created one page so far and that is index.php. I haven't moved on because my submit form isn't working like I want it to and I have no clue why it points me to that link after clicking on the submit button.

Comment: @Sean The only place I have <form method="GET" action="search.php" id="search"> is in my header.inc file and that's not even connected to my submission form.

Also, if I were to add search.php in place of the # I still get the same error code.

Comment: @Sean I've found the problem now. It was with the search bar. Thanks so much for helping me! I've been stuck on this for awhile now and I'm glad to move on from it. You are such a big help! thanks so much.

Comment: see my answer, the issue was due to not closing your input element inside your search form

Comment: Yeah, I see now. -.- All that over one thing not being closed. Thanks for all your help. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line in your `inc\incfiles\header.inc.php`

```
<input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search..."
```

You are missing the closing bracket -

```
<input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search..." />
                                                              ^^
```

because of that, the closing form tag on the next line is not beinging parsed, so your form in `index.php` is being nestled inside the `<form method="GET" action="search.php" id="search">`

Answer (score 1):

TRY USING $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I've tried this as well. But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

By staying on the same page , I think you mean you want to submit the page , refresh & send data. if you mean that , so you may use this as your  tag :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

However , if you want your page not to be refreshed , you need to work with Jquery , JavaScript etc.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's what I mean, sorry. But I've tried that code and I still get the same error.

Comment: look at your code ! there is an additional <form> tag ! After this code : `<center><h2>Join the community today!</h2></center>`. It may be the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of form `action="#"` write `form action=""` Notice there are 2 ticks with nothing in between.

Comment: As I stated in my post, I've already tried that and it didn't work at all. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: I get the same error as before.

Comment: What page does it send you to?

Comment: It sends me to an all white page that says : Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7